# Hibernate Criteria - how to filter on nested child?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I fear I may have phrased my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923948/hibernate-criteria-query-conundrum) badly, so I'm starting afresh for clarity.

Picture a number of tables for which there is a OneToMany association between each table; ***Farm -> Field -> RegionGroup -> Region***. I'm trying to construct a Criteria query that will filter on **Region.nutrient**. I've seen lots of examples of people filtering on attributes of the top level and sometimes the next level down, but am not sure how to construct the query when filtering four layers deep. At the moment I have this, which does not work;

```
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Farm.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .setFetchMode("fields.regionGroups", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("fields.regionGroups.regions", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .createCriteria("fields.regionGroups.regions").add(Restrictions.in("nutrient", nutrients));
```

What happens is that a primary SQL query is generated that correctly covers the desired outcome (and is exactly the set of data that should be being retrieved), however, when you iterate the returned objects, the association of **RegionGroup -> Region** is performed with a sub-query on each iteration that doesn't include the restriction, so I get all *Regions* of *RegionGroup*, irrespective of the value of *Region.nutrient*;

```
select
    ...
from
    Farm this_ 
inner join
    Business business3_ on this_.BusinessID=business3_.BusinessID 
left outer join
    Field fields4_ on this_.FarmID=fields4_.FarmID 
left outer join
    RegionGroup regiongrou5_ on fields4_.FieldID=regiongrou5_.FieldID 
inner join
    Region region1_ on regiongrou5_.RegionGroupID=region1_.RegionGroupID 
where
    region1_.nutrient in ( ? ) 

-------------------------------------------

select
    ...
from
    Region regions0_ 
where
    regions0_.RegionGroupID=?
```

What do I need to add so that the restriction specified against the association path **"fields.regionGroups.regions"** is enforced?

**EDIT:** The following HQL does what I'm after, but does not have the flexibility of definition that I'm after so I'd like to convert it to a Criteria query;

```
from Farm as farm
  inner join fetch farm.fields as field
  inner join fetch field.regionGroups as regionGroup
  inner join fetch regionGroup.regions as region
where farm.id in :farmId 
  and field.id in :fieldId
  and region.nutrient in :nutrients
```

Which gives me an output `List<Farm>` which can be iterated thusly;

```
Farm [shortName=XYZ, name=XYZ]
   Field [shortName=COMM, name=Common]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=1]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.869684]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=2]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.836086]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=3]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.954369]
```

So, how do I specify this as a Criteria query? To prove that it's doing what I want it to do, if I simply change the HQL and remove the restriction on the Region.nutrient, I get back all Regions for each RegionGroup;

```
from Farm as farm
  inner join fetch farm.fields as field
  inner join fetch field.regionGroups as regionGroup
  inner join fetch regionGroup.regions as region
where farm.id in :farmId 
  and field.id in :fieldId
```

With no changes to the code iterating the results, I now get this;

```
Farm [shortName=XYZ, name=XYZ]
   Field [shortName=COMM, name=Common]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=1]
         Region [nutrient=Mg, nutrientLevel=108.84927]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.869684]
         Region [nutrient=pH, nutrientLevel=6.727207]
         Region [nutrient=K, nutrientLevel=189.04442]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=2]
         Region [nutrient=Mg, nutrientLevel=108.6944]
         Region [nutrient=pH, nutrientLevel=6.7214856]
         Region [nutrient=K, nutrientLevel=188.38605]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.836086]
      RegionGroup [indexNo=3]
         Region [nutrient=K, nutrientLevel=190.72464]
         Region [nutrient=pH, nutrientLevel=6.736169]
         Region [nutrient=P, nutrientLevel=18.954369]
         Region [nutrient=Mg, nutrientLevel=109.54382]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight - do you expect that in the returned list of `Farm`s they will only have *some* `Region`s and `RegionGroup`s populated?

In other words, say I have a `Farm` with 2 `Field`s, each with 2 `RegionGroup`s, each with 2 `Region`s and only 1 of those `Region's has the`nutrient` you're looking for.

When you run your query, you'll get that `Farm` instance back (as you should - it satisfies the criteria). Now, do you expect that instance to only have 1 `Field` with 1 `RegionGroup` and 1 `Region` containing your nutrient?

That will not - **CANNOT** happen. Hibernate **guarantees** that in-memory representation of your object matches its persisted state (post-flush, of course) and doing something like above contradicts that principle. If this were possible, what would happen after you've decided to modify and save that `Farm`? Should Hibernate now remove all other `Field`s / etc... from the database?

If this is not what you're asking, please clarify your question.

Comment: In a word, yes. Each Farm may have multiple Fields and each Field will have multiple RegionGroups and each RegionGroup will have four Regions (one for each Nutrient being measured). If I'm only dealing with a particular Nutrient, I don't want to retrieve the Regions for those other Nutrients. The following HQL does exactly that and works perfectly - I just want to create a Criteria query version of it;

Comment: @ChssPly76: The statement, "Hibernate guarantees that in-memory representation of your object matches its persisted state", is false.  Proof is in the fact that you can apply a filter to an attribute of a child entity off your root entity (i.e. you can put a <filter> inside a <set>).  I just did it... and my subsets were all gracefully filtered irrespective of the integrity of the object's persisted state.  I want what Stu.C is asking for.  I want a sub-sub-sub-sub-collection to be filtered EXACTLY like how a sub-collection can be but hib ain't working with me. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have similar goal to fetch list of objects from the 3rd level with criteria matching 2 parameters: 1st id of the main parent entity and 2nd id of the inner most entity. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048663/how-to-create-hibernate-criteria-query-for-multiple-levels) (sorry I could only add it in the answer section as I wanted to get quicker attention and solution to my original question and I am unable to post it as a comment due to lower reputation on my profile). Thanks.